# add <a> tag into a class with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to add link to label tag the code is this:

```
    <div class="swatchinput">
       <label selectid="pa_color" class="attribute_pa_color_black wcvaswatchlabel wcvasquare"</label>
     <div>
```

how i can add `<a href="test.com">` then close that with  after `</label>` to make link.
i use this code with jquery but dosnt work fine

```
 $(".swatchinput").before( "<a href='https://yenial.ir'>" );
      $( "</a>" ).appendTo( ".attribute_pa_color_black" );
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the basics of jQuery and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't understand how HTML, DOM, jQuery works. What you need to know is:

1. You cannot have improper nesting (like `<a></label></a>`, which is what you are asking for I believe).
2. There is no selector like `$("</a>")`. Any tag starting with `/` is an ending tag.
3. You cannot wrap `<label>` with `<a>`.
4. You haven't closed the `<label>`'s starting tag correctly.
5. You haven't closed the `href` attribute correctly.
6. You cannot have `<a>` inside `<label>` or vice-versa.

Still you may continue to do what you wanna do, but the browser will push it out. So, considering the above points, what you need is:

```
$(".swatchinput").wrapInner( "<a href='https://yenial.ir'>" ); // Or
$(".swatchinput").append( "<a href='https://yenial.ir'>" );
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $(".swatchinput").append( "<a href='https://yenial.ir'>" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swatchinput">
  <label selectid="pa_color" class="attribute_pa_color_black wcvaswatchlabel wcvasquare"></label>
</div>
```

But when the above code is run (append `<a>` into `<label>`), the browser makes it this way:

[image: preview]

Comment: i try to get html result:
<div class="swatchinput">
<a href="https://yenial.ir">
       <label selectid="pa_color" class="attribute_pa_color_black wcvaswatchlabel wcvasquare"</label>
</a>
     <div>
tnx for complete answer but this is not solve my problem.